# Django permission inheritance problem and the Meta class

Tags: django, inheritance, permissions

I understand the Meta class can be inherited if the superclass has abstract=True, but can't be inherited otherwise. Is this because Django somehow consumes and removes the Meta class from concrete classes?  I'd like to do something as in the example below, so Derived can get the Meta properties from Base (in this case, to inherit permissions as part of django-guardian).

Is this possible?

```
class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("foo", "Allowed to do foo"),)

class Derived(Base):
    class Meta(Base.Meta): pass
```

Comment: So what's the problem with doing it as you're showing?

Comment: I wish I knew.  That is why I'm posting the question here.

Comment: I have the same problem. What is the work around to this so I can check the permissions using both the base class and the child class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance

The Meta class isn't inherited straightly, Django does some funky stuff and doesn't handle all of its attributes the same way. You can have a look [here](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/db/models/options.py#L57) if you like to know how the attributes on _meta are set.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking how to solve the problem for concrete inheritance, not abstract inheritance, only the latter of which is what the docs describe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case explicitly, inheriting the `Meta` class didn't work because of my use of the South tool. See [this ticket](https://web.archive.org/web/20150327125542/https://south.aeracode.org/ticket/211) for more info.

`django-admin.py syncdb --all` fixed the problem.