# Common app_label for all the models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have many classes in `models.py` something like:

```
class SomeClass1(BaseModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)

class SomeClass2(BaseModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    option_text = models.TextField()
```

Now, I want to add `app_label = 'my_app_label1'` to all of these classes, something like this:

```
class SomeClass1(BaseModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_app_label1'
```

But since there are many classes, so instead of adding `app_label = 'my_app_label1'` to all the classes, I'm adding `app_label = 'my_app_label1'` to the BaseModel, like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    """
    For future abstraction.
    """
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'ques_app_data'
```

After which I'm getting this error:

```
myapp.SomeClass1.basemodel_ptr: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'BaseModel', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

Can anyone please explain how to solve this ?

Comment: Does the name of your app match the name you pass to app_label?

Comment: Nope, it doesnt, but I want to give the same app_label for models across different apps

Comment: It has to be the same name it is included in settings, I think. Try that.

Comment: I want to give the same app_label for models across different apps

Comment: Why would you want to do that? app_label is used when you have models in  a place in which django doesn't know to which app they belong.

Comment: What version of Django are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post answers this question: 
[makemigrations not detecting changes for Extended Models in Django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639666/makemigrations-not-detecting-changes-for-extended-models-in-django-1-7)

having 2 major points:

1)  We must have

```
class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

in BaseClass

2) `app_label` ques_app_data is must be included in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying `abstract=True` in `BaseModel` inner `Meta` class.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    """
    For future abstraction.
    """
    class Meta:
        abstract=True # specify this model as an Abstract Model
        app_label = 'ques_app_data'
```

Then inherit this `BaseModel` class in your model classes.

All the child model classes inherit the `Meta` class attributes of parent `BaseModel` class. Django will make one adjustment though to the `Meta` class of an abstract base class, before installing the `Meta` attribute in a child class, it sets `abstract=False`. This is done so that children of abstract base classes don’t automatically become abstract classes themselves.

After doing this, you will need to run the migrations again.

**Note:** There must be an app in your project by the name `ques_app_data` for this to work.

Comment: Yes, I did this, but after this makemigrations is not creating the tables for child classes

Comment: What error are you getting? can you post the traceback

Comment: No Error. Normal Execution (without extending BaseClass)
Migrations for 'SomeClass1':
  0003_usersubscription2.py:
    - Create model UserSubscription2
But while extending BaseClass, I get nothing

Comment: Specifying a different name for `BaseModel` might help if migrations had been run without it being `abstract`. Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108899/using-django-south-to-move-from-concrete-inheritance-to-abstract-inheritance

Comment: Name is not BaseModel, it's something else

Comment: Try running  all the  migrations again using `migrate` command instead of `makemigrations`. Also check this similar link if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424262/django-permission-inheritance-problem-and-meta

Comment: Also, there must be an app in your project by the name `ques_app_data` to work.