# makemigrations not detecting changes for Extended Models in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-models

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'common',
    'users',
)
```

And

common/models.py:

```
class EduModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = 'ques_app_data'
```

users/models.py:

```
class UserSubscription2(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')

class UserSubscription3(EduModel):
    test2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

`makemigraions` is detecting changes for UserSubscription2, but not for UserSubscription3 (the child class). Can anyone please explain this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your `app_label` `ques_app_data` is not included in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'common',
'users',
'ques_app_data',
```

)

I am assuming you have the app `ques_app_data`. **If not then it's an issue, because `app_label` must refer to an existing `Django app`**.

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#app-label

Comment: On doing like this, I'm getting this error: ImportError: No module named ques_app_data

Comment: Got it..after creating an app ques_app_data it works !!